# is it good for SEO to hierarchy the site links?

Tags: seo, permalinks

One of my website i am using links like this:

- `http://example.com/web-development/`
- `http://example.com/web-designing/`
- `http://example.com/web-promotion/`

Not like this:

- `http://example.com/services/web-development/`
- `http://example.com/services/web-designing/`
- `http://example.com/services/web-promotion/`

can anyone tell me, is there any SEO point that i missed?? I means should i have to use the links like second example??

I think according to `breadcrumbs` view second example is good, but it would be great if i get some suggestion by SEO experts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question, which I answered if Slash or Hyphens are better for SEO:
[Is it better to use slash or hyphens for SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/is-it-better-to-use-slash-or-hyphens-for-seo/28403#28403)

Basically, Matt Cutts (from Google) stated (and recommends as a best practice) that Google treats hyphens in URLs as word separators, which would (in theory) weight subfolders differently than hyphens between words.

Comment: Great, nicely describe as i expect :) Thanks man..

Comment: glad to be of help ...